# Acknowledged messages are redelivered when crashed core client reconnects

Tags: java, hornetq

I have setup a standalone HornetQ instance which is running locally. For testing purposes I have created a consumer using the HornetQ *core* API which will receive a message every 500 milliseconds.

I am facing a strange behaviour on the consumer side when my client connects and reads all the messages from queue and if I forced shutdown this (without properly closing the session/connection) then next time I start this consumer again it will read the old messages from the queue. Here is my consumer example:

// HornetQ Consumer Code

```
   public void readMessage() {
    ClientSession session = null;
    try {
        if (sf != null) {
            session = sf.createSession(true, true);

            ClientConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(JMS_QUEUE_NAME);
            session.start();

            while (true) {
                ClientMessage messageReceived = messageConsumer.receive(1000);
                if (messageReceived != null && messageReceived.getStringProperty(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received JMS TextMessage:" + messageReceived.getStringProperty(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME));
                    messageReceived.acknowledge();
                }

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while adding message by producer.", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (HornetQException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while closing producer session,", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why it is working like this, and what kind of configuration should I use in client/server side so that if a message read by consumer it will delete this from a queue?

Comment: You appear to be using the HornetQ "core" API rather than JMS (since `ClientMessage` isn't a JMS object). Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes this is true ClientMessage is from HornetQ core API. But how is it relate with a problem ?

Comment: It's related to the problem because the two APIs behave differently.  You are likely not committing the session after the acknowledgements are complete. Are you committing the session at any point or are you creating the session with auto-commit enabled for acknowledgements?

Comment: I update code in question. This is how i am testing a consumer in HornetQ

Comment: I also tried with sf.createSession(true,false) but get same experience that message re delivered when client restart and connect with server. Is there any server side configuration required for this ? i don't want to set message expiry in queue but want to do that if message read by consumer then delete it from queue

Comment: Using `sf.createSession(true,false)` won't impact auto-commit for acknowledgements.  You'd need to use `sf.createSession(true,true)` or `sf.createSession(false,true)` as the boolean which controls auto-commit for acknowledgements is the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not committing the session after the acknowledgements are complete, and you are not creating the session with auto-commit for acknowledgements enabled.  Therefore, you should do one of the following:

- Either explicitly call `session.commit()` after one or more invocations of `acknowledge()`
- Or enable implicit auto-commit for acknowledgements by creating the session using `sf.createSession(true,true)` or `sf.createSession(false,true)` (the boolean which controls auto-commit for acknowledgements is the second one).

Keep in mind that when you enable auto-commit for acknowledgements there is an internal buffer which needs to reach a particular size before the acknowledgements are flushed to the broker. Batching acknowledgements like this can drastically improve performance for certain high-volume use-cases. By default you need to acknowledge 1,048,576 bytes worth of messages in order to flush the buffer and send the acknowledgements to the broker. You can change the size of this buffer by invoking `setAckBatchSize` on your `ServerLocator` instance or by using a different `createSession` method (e.g. `sf.createSession(true, true, myAckBatchSize)`).

If the acknowledgement buffer isn't flushed and your client crashes then the corresponding messages will still be in the queue when the client comes back. If the buffer hasn't reached its threshold it will still be flushed anyway when the consumer is closed gracefully.

Comment: It is still doing same way. I think i am doing something stupid either in my Producer OR Consumer code. I have updated a question again can you please have a look and suggest me is this a proper way to use autoCommit session in both place.

Comment: I have removed your producer code from the question as it's completely unrelated to the issue, and I've added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: Actually i am following an example which available in HornetQ source and for a Consumer implementation, it is not mentioned anything which use to set a MaxBatchSize after acknowledge. I am looking a documentation now to see how to set this info.

Comment: I already outlined the simplest ways you can set the acknowledgement batch size. As for the example in the HornetQ source, my guess is that it's relying on the `close()` invocation to flush the acknowledgement buffer or it's acknowledging enough messages to flush the buffer on its own. Can you provide a link to the relevant HornetQ source?

Comment: Perfect! ClientConsumer.Close() did this trick. Thanks for all this information.